# Memory Issues on iphone

Tags: iphone, security

I was developed one small iphone business application...In my application i used the data fetching from server..If that time the data will store on phone memory or RAM..I think its not secure... So I will decide to store another customized location....Is this possible in phone...Any good ideas?

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions. I'm leaving this one (the latest) open because it has an up-voted and accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want good security, you may want to receive the data in encrypted form, and decrypt only when you act on the data.