# iphone device memory issue

Tags: iphone, memory, device

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Memory Issues on iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074964/memory-issues-on-iphone)

Hello Everybody,

I was developed one small business iphone application...Actually whenever the program is  running it stores in application memory.. In same manner in device it stores device memory...

But in mac some times we can store the data like USE SECURE VIRTUAL MEMORY OPTION......
                So in the same manner is any possibilities are available  to store data in iphone device location for security purpose .... Any Ideas?

Comment: You really need to change the formatting on your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can take help from [Memory Management](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.... But i want another optional storage location in iPhone device..